# Find extrema on the interval

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization

**Problem**

Find the extrema of the function $$f(x) = cos^2(x)$$ on the interval $ [-4,4]$

I can differentiate and get $$f'(x) = -2 \sin(x) \cos(x)$$

And set that to zero, but I'm pretty sure that's not entirely correct.

Comment: I realize that it is easy to see what the answer is, but I would like to calculate it

Comment: $2\sin x \cos x = \sin 2x$ by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done correct, the exterma are found where the derivative is zero. Observe that: $$f'(x) = -2\sin(x)\cos(x) = -\sin(2x)$$

And find the solutions for $\sin(2x) = 0$. That is, $2x = n\pi$ for any integer $n$ so that the value is inside the interval $[-4,4]$.

Comment: You mean $-\sin(x) = 0$?

Comment: Then we divide by -1, nvm

Comment: Hm, when you say $2x= n \pi$ is this because $2x = arcsin(0)$ $$2x = 0 + k \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$$. I get pi divided by 2 because that's the period of sin?

Comment: @Paze All zeros of $\sin$ occur at the points $n \pi$ for integers $n$. That's why we get $2x = n \pi$ or equivalently $x = n \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What you've done is right - setting $f^\prime=0$. Find the solutions, say $x,y$. Then, choose a small $\epsilon$. Calculate
$$f^\prime(x+\epsilon),\quad f^\prime(x-\epsilon),\quad f^\prime(y+\epsilon)\quad f^\prime(y-\epsilon)$$
See if there is a sign change. Also, use the fact that $2\sin x\cos x=\sin(2x)$.